# how to add new column during runtime and then bind it to gridview?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql, gridview

how to **add new column during runtime to gridview**

here day by day products are supplied. use date as header columns(number of column is not default, it is depending upon number of days products supplied. for ex:8 means eight columns will create) and bind qty in item template(body).

```
**i want to display like this** 

            Totalqty Suppliedqty 01/12/13 01/12/13 01/12/13 01/12/13 01/12/13 01/12/13

    VacPan    50        25           8        5        4        1        2        3

    VacPan 
    Stub-in   100       50          10        8        7        8        7        10
    Kit
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom/modified datasource as per your need on runtime with the new column and bind your grid to it. Proceed on these lines.

Answer (score 0):

In every time you need to create new data source based on number days and then bind it to the gridview

Answer (score 0):

Make function for attendance report

```
public void BindAttendance()
    {

        ClearGrid();
        fyid =Convert.ToInt32(ddlYear.SelectedValue);
        dt.Clone();
        try
        {
            Session["datatable"] = null;
            dt = obj.AttendanceReport_Employee(fyid, Convert.ToInt32(ddlMonth.SelectedValue),Convert.ToString(EmpID));
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                divGrd.Visible = true;
                btnExcel.Visible = true;
                btnPrint.Visible = true;
                gvAttendanceReport.Visible = true;
                int count = dt.Columns.Count;
                this.gvAttendanceReport.DataSource = dt;
                this.gvAttendanceReport.DataBind();
                int i = 0;            
                    for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        DataColumn col = new DataColumn();
                        col = dt.Columns[j];
                        BoundField field = new BoundField();
                        field.DataField = col.ColumnName;
                        string text = col.ColumnName;
                        if (i != 0 && i != 1 && col.ColumnName!="Total Present" && col.ColumnName!="Total Absent" && col.ColumnName!="Total HalfDay" && col.ColumnName!="Total Late" && col.ColumnName!="Total Holiday")
                        {
                            field.HeaderText = text.Substring(0, 2);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            field.HeaderText = text;
                        }

                        gvAttendanceReport.Columns.Add(field);
                        i++;                       
                    }               

                gvAttendanceReport.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
                gvAttendanceReport.DataSource = dt; //a DataTable of your choice
                gvAttendanceReport.DataBind();
                Session["datatable"] = dt;


            }
            else
            {

                btnExcel.Visible = false;
                btnPrint.Visible = false;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
           gvAttendanceReport.DataSource = dt;
           gvAttendanceReport.DataBind();

           btnExcel.Visible = false;
           btnPrint.Visible = false;
        }

    }
```